# Spring data rest, default value for relationship property

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, jwt, spring-data-rest

I have User and Authority entities, connected ManyToMany relationship.
When I add new User using POST I want to set him default role for example role that exists "admin". I don't want to do that manually.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String username;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "user_authority", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
private List<Authority> authorities;
```

}

How can I do it? I know how to set default value for username but I don't know how to do that when it has relationship.

Thanks for help

Comment: You can use an Event Handler to do whatever is required: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#events

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve this with pure java:

```
private List<Authority> authorities = Arrays.asList(Authority.ADMIN);
```

So you, for example, have enum `Authority` and each `User` object you'll create in your system will have the `ADMIN` as an authority by default. Then when you save the user it's authority will also be saved.

Comment: Thanks for help, but how can I assign object which actually exist, for example authorityRepository findByName('ROLE_USER') returns object which I want to assign as default, is it possible?

Comment: You can implement this logic in constructor, for example. Create list -> find what you need -> add the item to the list -> assign the list to the field.